# How can I provide context to a URLStreamHandler?

Tags: java, url

Our application defines a URL scheme whose resolution is context-sensitive:  The content of the URL depends on the state of an in-progress database transaction.  As such, to retrieve the content I cannot, for example, open a new database connection.  However, I can't see a way to get at external context from the `URLStreamHandler` instance.

The documentation is a bit misleading, too:  I checked at [the java Protocol Handler](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/) site and it indicated (in the *Implementing URLStreamHandlerFactory* section) that the URL class would accept a `URLStreamHandlerFactory` instance, but the 1.5 JDK indicates that URL accepts only a `URLStreamHandler` when building a URL.

So, my question is, what is the best way to have context-sensitive URL resolution?  Is there any better way than to have a `ThreadLocal` class variable on my `URLStreamHandler` implementation, that is set before the calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for our purposes, at least, the thread-local context object works best.

Answer (score 2):

See [URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory(java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory))

This is a static method and:

> Sets an application's
>   URLStreamHandlerFactory. This method
>   can be called at most once in a given
>   Java Virtual Machine.